# Save sql query into external file

Tags: java, spring

i use Spring for DB operation. For now i save my sql query into a xml file, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">
<properties>
 <comment>This query returns something extremely useful.
 </comment>
 <entry key="date.sql">
 "update something set time = ? where sharedkey = ?"
 </entry>
</properties>
```

And in the JDBCTemplate i have this:

```
public Properties readProperties(String xmlFileName) throws Exception {
         Properties properties = new Properties();
         InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(xmlFileName);
         properties.loadFromXML(is);
         return properties;
        }

public void updateDate(){
properties = readProperties("queries.xml");
sqlQuery = properties.getProperty("date.sql");
jdbcTemplateObject.update(sqlQuery,new Object[] {time,token});
}
```

Work but i think is not the best solution, how i can that with Spring? or there is other library for that?

Comment: _I think its not the best solution_ what do you mean by this, from what perspective are you asking this question?

Comment: @HimanshuBhardwaj I wanted to separate the query from code

Comment: generally we use spring with hibernate or spring with JPA for DB calls.Are you using spring MVC?

Comment: @SpringLearner no i'm use Spring only for operation with db, i'm not work with spring-webmvc. So you advice to use Hibernate for separate query statement from code?

Comment: remember to use cdata for the sql. http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp.

Comment: @AntonioBalduzzi ORM like JPA/Hibernate decreases our burden.If your application is large enough then go for ORM.

Comment: Ok if you want to externalize the sqls, you can have a property file with all sqls in key-value pair. And let spring directly map these sqls to variable. Read about autowiring properties. But why such a design?

Comment: @HimanshuBhardwaj for more clean and maintainable code

Comment: If its just clean and maintainable code. I think you are over-engineering then. The only reason I see for externalizing queries, if you want to change them on the fly. A class with constants holding all the queries is sufficient else.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in multiple ways. the best way to follow is

1> By Placing the Queries in a Property File and call them using Spring PropertyPlaceHolder

2> You can Still Use XML and can Get the Query by using JAXB or SAX XML Parser.

Answer (score 0):

See the [ElSql](https://github.com/OpenGamma/ElSql) library which provides this functionality.

The small ElSql project allows an external file of SQL statements to be easily loaded and managed. It was originally written to work with Spring, and still does (although it now works without Spring as a dependency).

The file may be stored in "raw" SQL, or using a DSL:

```
-- an example comment
@NAME(SelectBlogs)
  @PAGING(:paging_offset,:paging_fetch)
    SELECT @INCLUDE(CommonFields)
    FROM blogs
    WHERE id = :id
      @AND(:date)
        date > :date
      @AND(:active)
        active = :active
    ORDER BY title, author
@NAME(CommonFields)
  title, author, content

// Java code:
bundle.getSql("SelectBlogs", searchArgs);
```

The DSL breaks the file into `@NAME` blocks that can be referred to from code. Each block is defined by significant whitespace indentation.

Additional tags can be used, such as `@PAGING` (that inserts the necessary code for paging such as FETCH/OFFSET) and `@AND` (that only outputs if the specified variable exists, for dynamically building searches). The goal of the optional DSL tags is to provide the common basics that often hit when trying to build dynamic SQL in a database-neutral way.

We use it for our SQL and avoid the significant overhead of an ORM.